# Set external program window on top or focus

Tags: c#, wpf, focus, external

So I have seen that been answered for C# winform but never for WPF.
All I have to do I to do is (pseudocode):

```
foreach(var p in process)
      if(p.name= "AAAA")
          p.window.focus();---->or better  p.window.BringOnFront();
```

this is why I have to launch an external program throught a thread. This program then start and launches a secondary window. This one has to be on top of all other windows
Thanx

Comment: Do all the processes have a window?  I know handling UW apps isn't very intuitive, so this could be tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this blog entry: http://ronniediaz.com/2011/05/03/start-a-process-in-the-foreground-in-c-net-without-appactivate/

It explains the SetForegroundWindow Windows API call which is what you need to use.

Comment: Either I went wrong or it doesn't work. I mean it starts but in my book      IntPtr splashwindow = FindWindowByCaption(IntPtr.Zero, "explorer.exe");
      SetForegroundWindow(splashwindow); should bring explorer to be brought up when launched minimized right? Well it doesn't

Comment: explorer.exe doesn't use "explorer.exe" as it's window title.  You need the actual title of the window.

Comment: Thanx that might be the reason. Can't it be used by process name? That would be safer since two windows may have the same title.

Comment: Yes, but it's a different API call to get a process handle from a running task.  Google is your best friend.